# Please clarify how to choose 屋根{やね} vs. 屋上{おくじょう}

Tags: word-choice

I am pretty confident in saying that **屋上** is a tangible location. Like:
"アパートの **屋上** に庭があります。"
"夏では、デパートの **屋上** にビアガーデンがあります。"

I've always thought of **屋根** as "ceiling" (but I've never really used it in practice). maybe:
"暑い時に、**屋根** に付けられた扇風器を点けます。"

So, what are the differences between **屋上** and **屋根** ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

屋上 = rooftop floor

[image]

屋根 = roof

[image]

ceiling = [天井]{てんじょう}

[image]

> アパートの 屋上 に庭があります。

Yes, you use 屋上 here. 「アパートの屋上に(は)庭があります。」

> 夏では、デパートの 屋上 にビアガーデンがあります。

You say 「夏には、デパートの屋上でビアガーデンが開催されます。」
「夏には、デパートの屋上にビアガーデンがオープンします。」etc.

> 暑い時に、屋根 に付けられた扇風器を点けます。

「暑い時(に)は、天井に(取り)付けられた扇風機をつけます。」